# pattern matching UNIX

Tags: perl, unix, design-patterns, matching

I am trying to achieve a pattern matching in perl code. I will give an example so it is easier to explain.

I am trying to use the following link in samtools -view:

ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data/HG00132/alignment/HG00132.mapped.SOLID.bfast.GBR.low_coverage.20111114.bam

samtools allows only a specific datasline to be retrieved with the following syntax:

samtools view -h ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data/HG00132/alignment/HG00132.mapped.SOLID.bfast.GBR.low_coverage.20111114.bam 1:123-1234

There are 1000 of them and the 'GBR' bit of the link changes. So I wrote a simple perl script and replace the link with 'ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data/HG00132/alignment/HG00132.mapped.SOLID.bfast.*.bam'. But it does not recognize the link. So I was wondering if there is similar way of using * in unix which you can use in the middle of the text rather than at the end. So I want to replace GBR with a star and also keep the 'bam' bit at the far end of the file name (I do not need to download the file.)

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you connecting to this ftp server using command line, right? Then I think you may try using get command with the pattern you want.

Comment: Hi tartar,i would like to use this line in a perl code actually. i do not want to download the file directly but use it from that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LWP to browse FTP. There are no hyper-links, so you have to parse the listing to distinguish among files you want to mirror. Shell globs like `*` do not work, but regex are suitable.

Untested example: collecting all `bam` URIs from the specified directory.

```
use File::Listing qw(parse_dir);
use LWP::UserAgent qw();

my @bam_files;

my $base = 'ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data/HG00132/alignment/';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $index = $ua->get($base);
for my $entry (parse_dir $index->decoded_content) {
    my $filename = $entry->[0];
    next unless $filename =~ /bam$/;
    push @bam_files, $base . $filename;
}
```

It is impossible to use an FTP file without downloading it first (see [method `get` in LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#REQUEST-METHODS)). This does not imply saving it also on the local filesystem (that would be method `mirror`).

samtools must do this behind the scenes, too, perhaps using protocol extensions to download only ranges, not the full file.

Comment: i am using the dataslice from Samtools and you dont need to download the actual file: samtools view -h ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data/HG00132/alignment/HG00132.mapped.SOLID.bfast.GBR.low_coverage.20111114.bam 1:123-1234

Comment: All this sort of crucial information belongs into the question, not scattered around as comments. [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9904013/edit) to amend.

Comment: 1. Then, what I would suggest is using a perl [ftp][1] module, not for downloading the file but running an ls command to list all files. 
 2. Then, you can use regular expressions to filter out all unnecessary files but the required ones. 
 3. Then, you will worked on that file list. Run any command you want on that list.


  [1]: http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html

Comment: The code above does exactly that. 1. LWP is an FTP-capable module. 2. The regex filters on `bam` files. 3. The matching URIs are collected into an array.

Answer (score 0):

From [wget advanced usage examples](http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/v1/wget_7.html#SEC33):

```
You want to download all the GIFs from an HTTP directory.
wget http://host/dir/*.gif doesn't work, since HTTP retrieval does not support
globbing. In that case, use:

wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.gif http://host/dir/
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not exactly after wget. i would like to use this line a perl code.